# Asp.net razor javascript avoid doing math on string

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a model:

```
public class VisitsTimelineModel
{
    public string Time { get; set; }

    public int Count { get; set; }

}
```

I fill and pass this model as viewbag to my view:

```
VisitsTimelineModel VisitsTimelineModel = new VisitsTimelineModel();
VisitsTimelineModel.Count = 10;
isitsTimelineModel.Time = "2/3";
```

then in my view in javascript section if I use below code:

```
alert((@Html.ViewBag.VisitsTimeline.Time).toString());
```

it will alert 0.666666 but I want output to be 3/2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the quotes in the alert statement.

```
alert("@Html.ViewBag.VisitsTimeline.Time");
```

I've also removed the unnecessary brackets and `.toString()` call.

Comment: Thanks Ted, so I don't need toString anymore

Comment: Exactly, as far as Javascript is concerned the alert function is just accepting a normal string literal.